# Weird Postgres Xlog

Tags: postgresql-9.4

I have question about Postgres xlog. According the Postgres documentation, the Postgres xlog should be in this format `0000000100000044000000FE`, i don t understand why the xlog format is my database is `000000010000004400000**5**FE`.  The additional 5 from where it comes...

Here real database xlogs for postgres 9.4

cat PG_VERSION
9.4

```
ll pg_xlog/ | tail -n 10
-rw——- 1 postgres postgres 2097152 May 12 03:24 0000000100000044000005FE
-rw——- 1 postgres postgres 2097152 May 12 03:24 0000000100000044000005FF
-rw——- 1 postgres postgres 2097152 May 12 03:24 000000010000004400000600
-rw——- 1 postgres postgres 2097152 May 12 03:24 000000010000004400000601
-rw——- 1 postgres postgres 2097152 May 12 03:24 000000010000004400000602
-rw——- 1 postgres postgres 2097152 May 12 03:24 000000010000004400000603
-rw——- 1 postgres postgres 2097152 May 12 03:24 000000010000004400000604
-rw——- 1 postgres postgres 2097152 May 12 03:24 000000010000004400000605
-rw——- 1 postgres postgres 2097152 May 12 03:24 000000010000004400000606
drwx—— 2 postgres postgres 45056 May 12 15:10 archive_status/
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: There's nothing extra. It's a continuous number that goes up every time a new log is created.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing "weird" about the filenames. You correctly stated that the filename should be in that **format** (the actual names will be **very** different in reality).

[Quote from the manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/wal-internals.html)

> Segment files are given ever-increasing numbers as names, starting at `000000010000000000000000`. The numbers do not wrap, but it will take a very, very long time to exhaust the available stock of numbers.

So the filename reflects an increasing number that has some structure in it. You can't expect any specific values in there, on a busy system they will simply keep increasing.

The first 8 digits (the `00000001`) reflect the [timeline](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/continuous-archiving.html#BACKUP-TIMELINES) of the WAL record if I am not mistaken, the rest the sequence number of the WAL record for that timeline.

Comment: According to Postgres documentation the xlog file name, should start from `000000010000004400000000` and ends at `0000000100000044000000FF`. A maximum of 255 segments per Xlog `0000000100000044`. So, having this segment file name `0000000100000044000005FE`, will be out of the rule.

Comment: @FadhelGhorbel: where did you find the reference that the name starts with `000000010000004400000000` and ends with `0000000100000044000000FF`? The part I quoted clearly states that the file name starts with `000000010000000000000000` and an "end value" is not mentioned anywhere

Comment: Here the reference https://www.depesz.com/2011/07/14/write-ahead-log-understanding-postgresql-conf-checkpoint_segments-checkpoint_timeout-checkpoint_warning/comment-page-2/#comment-595798

Comment: @FadhelGhorbel That is **not** the "Postgres documentation". And nowhere there does it claim that the filename will "start" with 000000010000004400000000. All file names shown in that blog are **only examples** they do not imply any "limits" on what the numbers can be.